# Get value of a key in hash of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash e.g.

```
{{"badan"=>1, "bau"=>1, "China,"=>1, "pilot."=>1, "RT"=>1, "penentu"=>1, "merupakan"=>1, "China, test test bau"=>1, "satu"=>1, "merupakan salah salah satu"=>1, "RT @WOWFakta: @WOWFakta: Di"=>1, "Di"=>1, "seorang pilot."=>1, "kelulusan menjadi menjadi seorang"=>1, "seorang"=>1, "salah"=>1, "@WOWFakta:"=>1, "satu penentu penentu kelulusan"=>1, "Di Beijing Beijing China,"=>1, "menjadi"=>1, "kelulusan"=>1, "test"=>1, "bau badan badan merupakan"=>1, "Beijing"=>1}=>{"kebali"=>1, "kff"=>1, "box"=>1, "@zannahoctavia"=>1, "kebali kamu kamu ca?"=>1, "ca?"=>1, "kampus"=>1, "kantin"=>1, "kff hah hah goods"=>1, "@zannahoctavia haha haha kali"=>1, "aja"=>1, "box kemang kemang aja"=>1, "yaa"=>1, "china"=>1, "hah"=>1, "hah. Jadi Jadi kebali"=>1, "goods pw pw tapi"=>1, "aja di di kff"=>1, "di"=>1, "pw"=>1, "kemang"=>1, "haha"=>1, "kali kantin kantin kampus"=>1, "Jadi"=>1, "tapi"=>1, "tapi yaa yaa hah."=>1, "kampus china china box"=>1, "hah."=>1, "kamu"=>1, "kali"=>1}}
```

and I want to retrieve all keys' values in a very efficient way. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to take the time to read through the documentation for Hash. It's obvious your hash wasn't created right, and wouldn't be how we'd normally want to create or use one. It is a good example that you can use any object as a hash key though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your hash contains a key and a value that is also a hash.  You can try the following

```
hash.flatten.map(&:keys).inject(:+)
```

or use `flat_map`

```
hash.flatten.flat_map(&:keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate your hash like that it contain hash within hash

```
h.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  value.values.each do |v|
    puts v
  end
end
```